# Xamarin forms how to pass parameters from page to tabbed page

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have problem to pass parameter from page. Goal is that after login wanna show logged user info in tabbed page. Can you help me how to pass parameter from page to tabbed page.

Thank you

Comment: Given that you haven't posted any code to illustrate what you're doing, it's impossible to give you a specific answer.  But generally speaking, a page is just a C# class and you can pass values using the constructor, a public method or property, or any other normal C# mechanism.

Comment: Show what you have tried, any errors?

Comment: No errors. I can't know how to plan process and also can't found any solutions yet. I tried to pass with constructor but no errors no result.

Comment: @Jason You are right :) everything is working well.
Thank you all guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution is**

Login Page

```
await Navigation.PushAsync(new TabbedPage1("Name"));
```

TabbedPage

```
<local:Page1 Title="Page1">
    <Label x:Name="lblfirstname"/>
</local:Page1>

public partial class TabbedPage1 : TabbedPage
{
    public TabbedPage1(string firstname) {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblfirstname.Text = firstname;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions, but it's depend on your implementation.

The simplest is use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) . Your tabbed page can subscribe and your page can publish all necessary parameters.